# Matlab find x of weighted average

Tags: matlab, weighted-average

How to find the weighted average x? From graphing x(y) it looks to be around x=0.45?

```
y = [0.1 0.1 0.2 0.5 0.4 0.2]
x = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6]
```

One way to perhaps compute it would to find x where the area under the curve y(x) is half of the area under the whole curve. But how to write that in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you intend `y` to be the weights, and you want to compute the weighted average of `x`, then the weighted average is simply

```
sum(x.*y) / sum(y)
```